# Wagtail version in admin interface does not update after upgrade

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I recently incrementally upgraded my Wagtail installation from 2.15.2 to 2.16.2, but the Wagtail version in the admin interface is still stuck in the old version. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: When you say 'in the admin interface' - where do you mean. In the sidebar menu or on the home (dashboard) page in the upgrade reminder. Also, what happens when you run `pip show wagtail | grep Version:` in the console?

Comment: It's both the sidebar menu and the upgrade reminder on the home dashboard page. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the console.

Comment: Seems odd. Are you sure the upgrade worked?

Comment: It's a strange one. I don't get the slim sidebar in the new admin interface, but when I ran a db migration I got the migrations below applied, which were consistent with my local upgrade testing. I should have mentioned this is running in Docker from Azure. 

`Applying taggit.0004_alter_taggeditem_content_type_alter_taggeditem_tag... OK
Applying wagtailredirects.0007_add_autocreate_fields... OK`

Comment: I also see this in the logs: `Successfully installed Django-3.2.14 Pillow-9.2.0 Willow-1.4.1...django-filter-21.1 django-modelcluster-5.3 django-taggit-2.1.0 django-treebeard-4.5.1 djangorestframework-3.13.1 draftjs-exporter-2.1.7 ...telepath-0.2 urllib3-1.26.10 wagtail-2.16 webencodings-0.5.1 xlrd-2.0.1 xlsxwriter-3.0.3 xlwt-1.3.0`. So it seems it did install Wagtail 2.16.

Answer (score 0):

As @LB Ben Jonston suggested, in the end the problem was even though the Docker image was built correctly, the image did not deploy correctly.

Since I'm not very familiar with Azure, I only checked that the pipeline ran correctly, image was built and pushed. But I missed checking that the actual CD task deployed the image successfully, which it didn't.

Comment: Glad to hear you got to the bottom of it.